# Mouse click detection

Tags: java, input, libgdx, mouseevent, mouseclick-event

I think i just need a little bit of correction on my code, but I can't figure out what im missing. Using input processor on Libgdx.

I want to add a new piece of food to an arraylist and draw it to the screen at the position of the mouse, but it does not draw.

here is my click detection:

```
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        if(Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Input.Buttons.LEFT)){
            Food foods;
            foods = new Food(new Sprite(new Texture("FlakeFood.gif")));      //sprite
            foods.setPosition(screenX, screenY);
            food.add(foods);
        }
```

here is the code that draws:

```
batch.begin();
for (int i = 0; i < food.size(); i++) {
            food.get(i).draw(batch);
        }
batch.end();
```

thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming `Food` class `extends` `Sprite` since you didn't put the code of `Food` and you are calling methods of the `Sprite` `class`

- The `screenY` that `touchDown` method gives you starts from top to
  bottom, meaning 0 is at the top of the screen and
  `Gdx.graphics.getHeight()` is at bottom of the screen. You should invert the `Y` position since libgdx draws `y-up` and `screenY` is `y-down` so It should be..
  `foods.setPosition(screenX, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-screenY);`
- Set the size of the sprite, I don't see you setting the size of the sprite, unless you have it set it up on the `Food` constructor you should set it. `foods.setSize(10,10)`
- Does the `touchDown` method even fire when you click? if not you should set the input processor `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this)` in the `create` method

```
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        System.out.println("Does this even run? if not, set the input processor Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this) in the create method");
        if(button == Input.Buttons.LEFT){
            Food foods = new Food(new Sprite(flakeFoodTexture));
            foods.setPosition(screenX, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()- screenY);// invert the Y position
            foods.setSize(10,10);// set the size
            food.add(foods);
        }
}
```

Comment: Both the first and the last tip helped a bunch, code works as intended now, thank you

Answer (score 0):

there are several mistakes in your code :

- don't create new Texture each time, create it once.
- use button parameter to check if it's left button.
- you need to convert from screen coordinates to your world coordinate

for the last one i suggest you to use a [viewport](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports) and then you can convert coordinates by using viewport.unproject method. You'll have to use viewport camera matrix with your batch as well in order to use same coordinates.